# Couldn't find Job with 'id'=:27

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am doing a query for

```
 @job = Job.find(params[:id])
```

the URL is 
http://localhost:3000/jobs/:27

so the params for the job id are in the url, and I know the job `27` exists. 
it works fine when I search

```
@job = Job.find(27)
```

so I think it is the colon that is causing the error. but its should work. It's driving me nuts. 
Is there a way to get rid of the colon or is there something simple I should be dong?

Comment: How are you creating that path in your view?

Answer (score 2):

Your url should be http://localhost:3000/jobs/27

When rails sees a route like `/jobs/:id`, it knows to translate the `:id` to a parameter. hence the reason you're able to do `params[:id]`. If the url is dynamically generated, I'd be curious to learn where you're setting the url.

Answer (score 1):

You might be having routes as:

```
resources :jobs
```

your jobs url creation in ROR should be:

```
link_to job_path(@job.id)
```

So this would generate url:

```
http://localhost:3000/jobs/27
```

Hence no colon should be generated in the url.

Answer (score 0):

In your show action, get rid of `@job` altogether and just use:

```
@job = Job.find(params[:id])
```

Answer (score -1):

apologies guys. Yes the error was when i was generating the url in the form. I had put the colon in there in front or the id...

so thats been resolved now.. should have worked that one out before i plastered it over the NEt :)